# Grafana summarize panels

Tags: grafana

Is there a way to summarize multiple singlestat panels in another singlestat panel Grafana?
In our Grafana monitoring we want to set up a drilldown layout. For this we need to summarize multiple singlestat panels into one. These singlestat panels either display 1 (working) or 0 (not working). The summarized panel should also display either 1 (all panels are 1) or 0 (at least one of the panels is 0).

Answer (score 1):

You can summarize it on the query level - query must return one value (because singlestat panel), which aggregates results of all tests, which you want to represent.

Another option is non singlestat panel, where you can aggregate multiple queries - for example [polystat plugin](https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-polystat-panel).